# How to load .mat in c++ using "Matlab Data / Engine API for c++"

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to include a .mat in a C++ program. However, I am not able to use the conventional `"mat.h"` to do this due to internal compatibility problems between the Matlab API for C (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-c-api-to-read-mat-file-data.html) and the one for C++ (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-data-array.html). Does someone know of a method to achieve this with the new API?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got a rather suboptimal solution. For those who might run into this problem as well, here it is what i got so far:

```
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include "MatlabEngine.hpp"

    using namespace matlab::engine;
    // Start MATLAB engine synchronously
    std::unique_ptr<MATLABEngine> matlabPtr = startMATLAB();
    std::vector<double> labels_cpp;

    // Create figure window
    matlabPtr->eval(convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("m = matfile('labelsOfGist.mat'); labels = m.labels;"));

    //Get figure handle and Units property
    matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
    matlab::data::TypedArray<double> labels = matlabPtr->
        getVariable(convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("labels"));

    size_t elements = labels.getNumberOfElements();
    labels_cpp.reserve(elements);
    std::insert_iterator<std::vector<double>> insert_it(labels_cpp, labels_cpp.begin());
    std::copy(labels.begin(),labels.end(), insert_it);
```

If someone gets a better solution for this, please let me know :)

Comment: That does indeed look rather suboptimal, needing to connect to MATLAB. The C++ data interface is very new. Maybe they haven’t gotten around to adding MAT-file reading yet?

Comment: Yes, that might be te problem :/