# How to load a mat file in c++ using the "Matlab Data API for c++" WITHOUT the Matlab Engine?

Tags: c++, matlab

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50152254/17059713) was asked previously on how to load data from a mat file in c++. OP found a non-ideal solution which involved using the matlab engine to load data from a mat file. As I understand it, using the matlab engine effectively starts matlab, which is nonideal for code performance. Some of the comments indicate that the knowledge base on the Matlab Data API was very small when the question was asked. Does anyone have a better method to load data from a mat file in c++ without using the matlab engine?

Comment: MATLAB comes with a shared library for reading MAT-files and manipulating the resulting `mxArray`s. Using it doesn’t require starting MATLAB. You can use either the old C matrix API or the new C++ Data API. Just read [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-data-array.html).

Comment: MATLAB Data API has nothing to do with mat file. It includes a series of array data types and containers that you can use to store and retrieve data just like for example std::vector. The main difference with std::vector is that those containers are compatible with the internal data types that are used in MATLAB interpreter/engine so you can use them to send /receive data to/from engine without the cost of copy.

Comment: It looks as if the relevant libraries are documented [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html)?